# AAD B2C newUser Attribute

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How can I manipulate the built in newUser attribute of AAD B2C?
[image: Screenshot of the newUser attribute]

I am using the Graph API to get and update user information currently, but can't figure out what value I need to send with the update user Patch to change this bool.

I need a way to programmatically set this attribute to true or false. I can't seem to find it's documentation either.

Comment: These are the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) you can update on the user.

Comment: is the newUser attribute perhaps an extension?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we can't do this because "newUser" is not a property of [AAD user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Not all the claims included in access token are the properties of the user.

And based on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#outputclaims), it should only be returned as `true` when the user is newly created. We should not update it.